# Can let replace var in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm from a Java background and started learning JavaScript.

Declaring variables in JavaScript using the keyword `let` sounds like is uses  similar scope rules of declaring variables in Java. The concept of hoisting in JavaScript is confusing (consider my C++/Java background) and I don't see any pitfalls in using `let` in place  of `var`.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

Some experts even recommend solely using `let` everywhere, if it is available in your environment (Douglas Crockford said it in his Pluralsight course JavaScript the Good Parts).

`ESLint` even has a [rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var) not to use `var` in ES6 Environments.

Comment: Ohh how painfully wrong this answer is. Let should be limited inside of scopes and areas where it needs to be. Const and let are not replacements of let and it is wrong and a band wagon to believe so. I highly recommend watching this: https://www.lynda.com/JavaScript-tutorials/Let-vs-var/604265/618412-4.html

Comment: i support the point made by @TheBlackBenzKid. let is *not* the new var.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. However, assuming you're developing for the web; Be sure to read browser compatibility first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Well, I'm learning Java Script as i'll have to (in fact started working on server side) use nodejs.